# Can we extend a template in multiple templates?

Tags: django, deployment, jinja2, backend, extends

In Django while making templates, I created a master template where I used 3 template block tags and 2 different html files for extending (using extends template tag) and code for them. only one html code is added to master template, the other one is not added. Can we simultaneously extend a template in multiple templates?

I was trying to make 2 files that extends a master template. but only one template's code is being added when I see in 'view source code'.

Comment: Perhaps your a mixing [`extends`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) and [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include). A template can only extend one base template but include as many templates as you like/need.